# Special characters appearing in HTML format

Tags: html, mysql, perl, browser

I have a legacy application developed in Perl, Apache and Mysql.

Some of the sections in application display HTML codes for the character. The problem is isolated to the following characters on the keyboard:

1. semicolon
2. comma
3. quotation marks
4. less than symbol
5. greater than symbol

[image: Refer the screenshot.]

The table which stores this data is also storing the data like this itself. The table is CHARSET=latin1.

[image: Refer DB screenshot.]

The application is using

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

in the HTML rendering.

My Question is "How to solve this issue"?

- Should I be making some changes to the DB charset ? ( I have multiple
  places in the application where this is broken and multiple tables
  are used in various sections )
- should I be making some changes in the PERL DB Connection? ( This looks like the best place to handle the issue as this is common to any module which uses the DB interaction ) Module so that it will decode/encode the special characters.

Any Other suggestions?

Comment: How does the data get stored in the DB? Is there some code that converts actual user input so that e.g. the Ascii apostrophe (') gets converted to `&#39:`? (There is no real reason to do so, but legacy code often does odd things.) How is the data from the DB inserted into the HTML document? If you just insert `&#39:`, it gets displayed as an Ascii apostrophe, so the code must be doing something else.

Comment: Probably the HTML rendering section of the code doesn't know that the text in the database is already escaped for special characters;  so it escapes it one more time before rendering the html.

Comment: IMO this is a database problem: the latin-1 character set supports the entities that are currently encoded, so they should be changed back to the appropriate characters so information can be viewed directly in the database without requiring any mental gymnastics to convert `&#39;` to an apostrophe, etc. If the db data is be output to a medium where certain entities do require encoding--e.g. to a webpage, where `<` and `>` need to be encoded--the code producing the web page output should do this conversion.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't look like a DB charset issue, it looks like an HTML escaping issue. It appears that you have pre-escaped character entity references in the data values that would normally be unescaped by an HTML browser, but they are inside a text box and escaped. How do they get rendered? By some AJAX code that isn't properly rendering escapes?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Character_entity_references_in_HTML

Comment: @ialarmedalien - Not sure what you are referring to. Perl legacy apps have AJAX too. I was just supposing how the field could be populated if it wasn't rendered by the browser. AJAX was the most likely explanation. My answer is just my best guess.